# How to retrieve the value of a key from properties file in spring using Autowiring

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring,  i have a properties file  from which have to read a particular key. I have to use the auto wiring feature.I am giving the code what i have done so far,

```
<bean id="dnqLtrBatchWorkflow" class="com.twentyfirst.dnqltrbatch.beans.DNQLtrBatchWorkflow" >
    <property name="pldwDataSource" ref="pldwDS" />
    <property name="builder" ref="documentBuilder" />
    <property name="externalLib" value="${pldw.library_name1}"></property> // i want to read this key from the properties file 
</bean>



public class DNQLtrBatchWorkflow extends NonTransactionalAbstractWorkflow<DNQRecord> {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(DNQLtrBatchWorkflow.class);
@Autowired
private String externalLib;

 public void aMethod(){

  System.out.println(externalLib); //  i want to print the value here.
  }

 //properties file 
pldw.connection.url=jdbc:as400://OHINDIBMP1:446/TSL50LIB00
pldw.jdbc.username=TSVQTEBAT1
pldw.jdbc.password=LtxQ8jqGcXcfWnGAtot8fw==
pldw.driverClassName=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
pldw.library_name1=TSL50LIBIS
```

But when i am trying to run this i am getting below exception

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dnqLtrBatchWorkflow': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.twentyfirst.dnqltrbatch.beans.DNQLtrBatchWorkflow.externalLib; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
```

this key pldw.library_name1 i have to get in the class  DNQLtrBatchWorkflow.Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: You cann not autowire a string. You only can autowire beans.

Comment: @Jens thanks for the reply but how i will get the key value in that class ?

Answer (score 1):

With the Definition of the bean:

```
<bean id="dnqLtrBatchWorkflow" class="com.twentyfirst.dnqltrbatch.beans.DNQLtrBatchWorkflow" >
    <property name="pldwDataSource" ref="pldwDS" />
    <property name="builder" ref="documentBuilder" />
    <property name="externalLib" value="${pldw.library_name1}"></property> // i want to read this key from the properties file 
</bean>
```

The setter for the property `externalLib` is called.

So you have to add the setter for the property and than you can print it out:

public class DNQLtrBatchWorkflow extends NonTransactionalAbstractWorkflow {

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(DNQLtrBatchWorkflow.class);

private String externalLib;

 public void aMethod(){

  System.out.println(externalLib); //  i want to print the value here.
 }

 public void setExternalLib(String value){
     this.externalLib = value;
 }
```

The above code should work, if you have configured the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with annotation based class configuration I think what you are looking for is **@Value** and not **@Autowire**.

Make sure your property file is on the classpath than annotate your field like this:

```
@Value("${pldw.library_name1}")
private String externalLib;
```

This has the benefit that you doesn't even have to write the setter for the field. And remove the property tag from your bean definition.

For more usage of **@Value** check this: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation

Comment: I am getting this exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'pldw.library_name1' in string value "${pldw.library_name1}"
        at

Comment: You also need to have a property placeholder configurere bean which tells to spring where to find the properties. Like this: 
`<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
   <list>
    <value>whatever.properties</value>
    <!-- List other property files here -->
    <!-- value>mail.properties</value -->
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>`